# Implement an interfaces with multiple inheritance in a Nodejs class

Tags: javascript, node.js, interface, multiple-inheritance

I tried the following way to create an interface and implement it.

```
class AInterface {
  constructor () {
    if (!this.methodA) {
      throw new Error('class should implement a methodA() method')
    } else if (!this.methodB) {
      throw new Error('class should implement a methodB() method')
    }
  }
}
export default AInterface
```

implemented that in a class by extending it. (Note that I have used ts-mixer to have multiple inheritance.

```
import AInterface from './AInterface'
import { Mixin } from 'ts-mixer'

class ClassA extends Mixin(AnotherClass, AInterface) {

  constructor () {
    super()
  }

  methodA () {
    return 'test'
  }

  methodB () {
    return 'test'
  }

}
export default ClassA
```

This will throw the error `class should implement a methodA() method`. Which means the check I do in the interface fails  `if (!this.methodA)`.
This works fine when I remove the Mixin and extend only the interface. (`class ClassA extends AInterface`)

Is there a better way to do this or how can I fix this?

Node version - 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the constructor of `AInterface` does not get the right `this`. So it does not see the `methodA` or `methodB`.

The workaround is to avoid doing that check in the constructor.

```
import AInterface from "./AInterface.mjs";
import { Mixin, settings } from "ts-mixer";

settings.initFunction = "init";

class ClassA extends Mixin(AnotherClass, AInterface) {}
```

AInterface.js

```
class AInterface {
  init () {
    if (!this.methodA) {
      throw new Error('class should implement a methodA() method')
    } else if (!this.methodB) {
      throw new Error('class should implement a methodB() method')
    }
  }
}
export default AInterface
```

Notice the use of `init()` method above.

Comment: If the constructor does not get the right `this` value, that sounds very much like a bug in that `ts-mixer` library?